# finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list does not work

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When I tried `-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=arch/arm/boot/dts/`and compiled the kernel ,`__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit` are not getting called for any function. Normal `-finstrument-functions` works properly. My gcc version is `4.8.4`

Comment: It seems that normal option `-finstrument-functions` is still needed when you use `-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev How do I add it? I mean in the same line with space ?

Comment: Yes, options should be space-separated.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I gave like this `KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=arch/arm/boot/dts/ -finstrument-functions` and it still adds profile functions to those in `dts` folder

Comment: Can you provide an example of the function in `dts` directory, which is still instrumented with these two options?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It worked after changing the makefile as `-finstrument-functions -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=arch/arm/boot/dts/`. If you could post the comment as answer I will accept it.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option for limit instrumentation `-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list` doesn't work without instrumentation option itself (`-finstrument-functions`). Proper way for use these options together:

```
-finstrument-functions -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=arch/arm/boot/dts/
```